# How to fix a vulnerable dependency using cmd?

Tags: laravel, npm, dependencies

In this case, I have a bit of knowledge of dependency.

I have this warning on CLI

```
int: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Patch failed at 0006 Modified resources
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

Can someone help me explain on the warning?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `git add .` – don't omit the dot(.) Next run `git commit -m "your commit msg"`  finally run the previous command you were trying, I presume `git rebase`

Comment: Thank you Igiri this is already been solved. Thank you anyway and God bless you.